# Windows gMSA How To Secure Use of CredentialSpec Used By Docker Container Engine

Tags: windows, active-directory, docker, kerberos

The gMSA strategy Microsoft recommends for Containers [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/group-managed-service-accounts/group-managed-service-accounts-overview) and [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/manage-serviceaccounts) works very well.  The general idea is the Container host retrieves the gMSA password from an Active Directory domain controller and gives it to the Container.  The Identity configuration is stored in a JSON Credential Spec file, which is expected to live at the location `C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\CredentialSpecs` on the Container host.  This file contains metadata about the gMSA and is ultimately passed to the Docker Engine that runs the containers.  Below is an example of doing this via docker run:

```
docker run --security-opt "credentialspec=file://myspec.json" --hostname myappname -it myimage powershell
```

The issue with this is if multiple teams use the same Container hosts, how can you protect against one team from using another team's Credential Spec and thus run their containers with that team's permissions?  For example, if the host has the below CredentialSpecs, Team A could use Team C's.

```
C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\CredentialSpecs\\TeamA.json
C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\CredentialSpecs\\TeamB.json
C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\CredentialSpecs\\TeamC.json
```

Comment: If a server is authorized to retrieve credentials for a GMSA, any user with sufficient access to that server can use that GMSA -- regardless of the CredentialSpecs. For example, you can start an arbitrary process using PSExec64.exe -i -u DOMAIN\gMSA-Account$ -p ~ powershell.exe

Answer (score 0):

Even tho I did not read nor use that technology, I suggest NTFS permissions.
Remove permissions on the files and only apply read permission for the allowed group or user.
Docker can't read the credential file and thus can't run under a different/unallowed user.
Only works if docker also runs under different user contexts.

Comment: Dockerd actually runs as "SYSTEM" so this probably wouldn't work 